# Does wget -w option not work with -p?

Tags: wget

When I run `wget64.exe -p -w 10 http://www.example.com` on Windows command line for a site with many images, I expect based on documentation for `-w` to cause this to space out all its image downloads by 10 seconds each. But it does the whole thing with no waits - is this because `-w` isn't meant to work with `-p`? Does grabbing the images linked in a page somehow "not count" as making an additional request from the server? Or am I using incorrect syntax?

Comment: -w is for a delay between retrievals, not requests.

Comment: @pvg Thank you for clearing that up for me. Is there a way to achieve something similar for spacing out individual requests?

Answer (score 0):

`wget64.exe -r -l 1 --wait=10 http://www.example.com` should do what you want.  It splits the page dependencies into retrievals and applies the wait time instead of combining them all into a single page request.

Comment: Running that still has it downloading all the images in one go, no wait times.

Comment: That's odd. It works for me.  Try `--wait=10` instead of `-w`.  Could be a qwerk of the 64bit version.

Comment: Still not working. I've tried a couple of different sites, too  - the wait time doesn't seem to work at all.